# inequality with sums and logarithms

Tags: inequality, summation, logarithms

How do you show that:
$\ln(x!) ≥ \frac{x-1}{2}\ln(x)$  for every positive integer value of $x$ (except $0$)

my attempt was putting it in summation notation since $\frac{x-1}{2}= \frac{1}{x} \sum\limits_{n=1}^xn$ and $\ln(x!) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^x\ln(n)$
which changes the inequality to $x\sum\limits_{n=1}^x\ln(n) \geq \ln(x) \sum\limits_{n=1}^xn$
or simply $[\ln(x)+\ln(x-1)+...]x \geq [x+(x-1)+...]\ln(x)$
and doing e^(both expressions) gives me:
$(x-1)^x(x-2)^x... \geq x^{x-1}x^{x-2}...$ but where do I go from there, or is this even correct. (btw: my teacher said Taylor series is not allowed, don't know if that helps)

Comment: "for every integer value of $x$ (except $0$)"? Are you considering negative integers? It should be "for every **positive** integer value of x".

Comment: It is just about as easy to prove the stronger $$\log(n!)\ge\frac{n-1}2\log(2n)$$ for every positive integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By exponentiating, you get $(x!)^2\ge x^{x-1}$ This is true for $x=1$, and for $x>1$ just notice that the left side is:

$$(2x)(3(x-1))(4(x-2))\ldots ((x-1)\cdot 3)(x\cdot 2)$$

which has $x-1$ factors, and every one of them is greater than $x$ (try proving that as a small exercise), so the whole product is greater than $x^{x-1}$.

Comment: wow, thank you. This was such a clever way of solving the problem. Thank you